# How do I find the distribution function of uniform distribution on $\{-1,0,1\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I only know that if it is uniformly distributed the formula for probability function will be $\frac{1}{b-a}$ but in my question I have a uniform distribution on $\{-1,0,1\}$.

For example if $X$ has uniform distribution on $(a,b)$ then it will be

$F(x) \begin{cases} 0 & x < a \\
       \frac{x-a}{b-a} &  a \le x \le b \\
        1 & x > b \end{cases}$

How do I find uniform distribution on $\{-1,0,1 \}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Find the uniform distribution"? Do you mean you want to find a distribution _function_?

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right

Comment: Just note that the distribution function of the uniform distribution on interval $(a,b)$ is $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ for $x \in (a,b)$, zero for $x<a$ and $1$ for $x > b$. I edited your question in accordingly.

Comment: The [(continuous) uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) on the interval $[a,b]$ has density $\frac{1}{b-a}$ in that interval, while the [(discrete) uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) on the integers $\{a,a+1,\ldots,b\}$ has probability mass function $\frac1{b-a+1}$ on those integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't $\{-1,0,1\}$ a set with three elements? In that case we have $P[-1]=P[0]=P[1]=1/3$ and zero otherwise. The distribution function will be
$$
F(x) \begin{cases} 0 & x < -1 \\
       1/3 &  -1 \le x  < 0 \\
       2/3 &  0 \le x  < 1 \\
        1 & x \ge 1 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: why is it 1/3?? sorry for asking

Comment: Is it because we divide the elements -1, 0, 1 = which is 3?

Comment: @헬창공돌이: Yes, we have three elements which can occur with the same probability, hence occuring of one has probability 1/3. This is similar to probability of some outcome on a dice which is 1/6. This is because the dice has six sides.